# Firing a Button's Click event from outside Button

Tags: .net, winforms, events, button

I have a Button and I need to fire it's Click event externally from actually clicking it. However, the code

```
myButton.Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

gives me the error

```
The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Click' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx) type has a [`PerformClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) method that does exactly what you want.

Comment: What confused me is that in my own events i call the event like a method, and i was wondering why i couldn't do so here.

Comment: @RCIX: Well, it's been over two years since you asked this; but I *just* realized that I never responded to your comment. You probably already know this now, but for posterity: events can only be "called" like methods from within the class in which they are defined. This is why you can fire your own custom events from within the code where you define them but can't directly fire events on external classes, including `System.Windows.Forms.Button`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Button button = new Button();
button.PerformClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just fire the event directly?

If you're event is called `myButton_Click` you can simply call it from wherever in the page

`myButton_Click(myButton, EventArgs.Empty);`

Comment: I could do that, but i'm trying to do it this other way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Click is an event, not a method.

You can invoke the method witch one has added to the event.